# How to use computed property of "needs" controller in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I want to build a small shop with two different product types `fruits` and `vegetables`. Each have a own page in my shop, what are separated routes, controllers and models for each. For both product categories I want to calculate the sum of 'ordered' items.

On a third page, called 'totals', I want to display both sums (fruit and vegetables) and the total sum of both. Therefore I am loading the two controllers of the product types like so: `needs: ['BasketsFruits', 'BasketsVegetables']`.

**Question:** Why are the sums of fruits and vegetables not updated on the totals-page when I change the quantity of items on the other pages? Is my general approach right?

**Example:** Everything working except the sum on the totals-page. [Example in a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tamihatole/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```js
$(function () {
    App = Em.Application.create();

    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

    App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend();
    
    App.BasketsFruitsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      totalSum: function() {
        var sum = 0;
        this.forEach( function (entry) {
          sum += parseInt(entry.get('quant'));
        });
        return sum;
      }.property('@each.quant')
    });
    
    App.BasketsVegetablesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      totalSum: function() {
        var sum = 0;
        this.forEach( function (entry) {
          sum += parseInt(entry.get('quant'));
        });
        return sum;
      }.property('@each.quant')
    });
    
    App.BasketsTotalsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
      needs: ['BasketsFruits', 'BasketsVegetables'],
      fruits: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.BasketsFruits.totalSum"),
      vegetables: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.BasketsVegetables.totalSum")
    });
    
    App.Fruits = DS.Model.extend({
      title: DS.attr('string'),
      color: DS.attr('string'),
      quant: DS.attr('int')
    });
    
    App.Vegetables = DS.Model.extend({
      title: DS.attr('string'),
      season: DS.attr('string'),
      quant: DS.attr('int')
    });

    App.Fruits.FIXTURES = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Banana',
        color: 'yellow',
        quant: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Apple',
        color: 'red',
        quant: 0
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Melon',
        color: 'green',
        quant: 0
      }
    ];

    App.Vegetables.FIXTURES = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Asparagus',
        season: 'spring',
        quant: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Pumpkin',
        season: 'fall',
        quant: 0
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Cabbage',
        season: 'winter',
        quant: 0
      }
    ];
    
    App.Router.map(function() {
      this.resource('index', { path: '/' });
      this.resource('baskets', { path: 'baskets' } , function() {
        this.route('index', { path: '/' });
        this.route('fruits', { path: 'fruits' });
        this.route('vegetables', { path: 'vegetables' });
        this.route('totals', { path: 'totals' });
      });
    });

    
    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('baskets');
      }
    });
    
    App.BasketsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('baskets.fruits');
      }
    });

    App.BasketsFruitsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return this.store.find('Fruits');
      },
      renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('fruits');
      }
    });

    App.BasketsVegetablesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return this.store.find('Vegetables');
      },
      renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('vegetables');
      }
    });

    App.BasketsTotalsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('totals');
      }
    });

});
```

```css
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-tabs>li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: 2px 2px 0 0;
    padding: 2px;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        {{#link-to "baskets.fruits" class="button" tagName="li"}}
            <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Fruit Basket</a>
        {{/link-to}}
        
        {{#link-to "baskets.vegetables" class="button" tagName="li"}}
            <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Vegetable Basket</a>
        {{/link-to}}
        
        {{#link-to "baskets.totals" class="button" tagName="li"}}
            <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Totals</a>
        {{/link-to}}
    </ul>
    
    <div id="main">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="fruits">
    Select your fruits:
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
    <li>
        {{item.title}} ({{item.color}})
        {{input
        type="number"
        step="1"
        placeholder="0"
        value=item.quant
        }}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    You have {{totalSum}} fruits.
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="vegetables">
    Select your vegetables:
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
    <li>
        {{item.title}} ({{item.season}})
        {{input
        type="number"
        step="1"
        placeholder="0"
        value=item.quant
        }}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    You have {{totalSum}} vegetables.
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="totals">
    What you have selected:
    <p>{{fruits}} fruits and {{vegetables}} vegetables</p>
</script>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.8.1/ember.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/1.0.0-beta.12/ember-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: You got all the code - why not throw this into a jsbin? Just saying... ;)

Comment: @KalmanHazins : I am not familiar to jsbin? What does it more than the code snippet here?

Comment: @KalmanHazins Did it.

Comment: it lets you play/test code in real-time instead of trying to "guess"

Comment: see what I mean about playing real time and getting to the bottom of things QUICKLY? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were **real** close

The controllers need to be lowercased as in:

```
App.BasketsTotalsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['basketsFruits', 'basketsVegetables'],
  fruits: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.basketsFruits.totalSum"),
  vegetables: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.basketsVegetables.totalSum")
});
```

Working [here](http://jsbin.com/zameki/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Ok, this was really close. Sometimes it does really help to create a minimal example of a more complex problem.

Comment: Is there a way to get ember to log a message to debug such situations? Or did you just "see" it?

Comment: I guess I just "saw it"